# Make sound settings created by ffmpeg apply to entire Windows applications

Tags: ffmpeg, windows

The recording sound of my microphone is weak, so I resorted to using ffmpeg to add a volume increase effect and some other effects. I created a simple batch file and recorded the sound with it, and it works very well. This is the batch file code:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (USBAudio2.0)" -channels 1 -af " stereotools=level_in=2 , afftdn=nf=-25 , volume=10 " Output.wav
```

But the problem occurs when I want to make calls or use the microphone in Windows applications, the recording is very weak. Is there a way to make the ffmpeg effects that are in the batch file apply to all system applications, and how can that be done?

I searched and found that I have to create a virtual microphone device with some programs and make it the main microphone for the system. I tried these programs, but there was no option to add ffmpeg codes or pass the audio through the batch file that I created earlier.

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong thing - sort out your microphone levels and the problem is solved. Don't use ffmpeg as a kludge to fix a very basic issue.

Comment: I raised the volume levels on my microphone to the highest level, but the recording still sounded weak. I also prefer ffmpeg because it gives me more freedom to adjust the audio settings.

Comment: raising volume levels on the mic is not the solution I was suggesting. Your mic appears to be the problem - get a better mic and audio interface. Nothing else will help if those aren't sorted.